# Enabling word suggestion while typing in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview

On my textfield/textview I want to enable auto suggestion of words so that when user starts typing,  the possible dictionary word is suggested and user need not to type more.

I have tried below but they are not the one I am looking for:

```
[myTextView setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes];
[myTextView setSpellCheckingType:UITextSpellCheckingTypeYes]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think iOS comes with an autocomplete feature, but you can roll your own pretty easily; just follow [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/336/how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values).